# Toast.makeText ANR

Tags: android, freeze, android-anr-dialog, android-toast

I'm getting an ANR that seems to be from Toast.makeText:

> DALVIK THREADS: (mutexes: tll=0 tsl=0 tscl=0 ghl=0 hwl=0 hwll=0)
>   "main" prio=5 tid=1 SUSPENDED | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0
>   obj=0x40163600 self=0x12620 | sysTid=4197 nice=0 sched=0/0
>   cgrp=default handle=-1345338264 | schedstat=( 149532214000 43042125000
>   324000 ) utm=13923 stm=1030 core=0 at
>   android.graphics.Matrix.native_create(Native Method) at
>   android.graphics.Matrix.(Matrix.java:49) at
>   android.view.View.(View.java:1852) at
>   android.view.View.(View.java:2411) at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.(ViewGroup.java:365) at
>   android.widget.LinearLayout.(LinearLayout.java:156) at
>   android.widget.LinearLayout.(LinearLayout.java:152) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:416) at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:576) at
>   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
>   at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:644)
>   at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:669)
>   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:457) at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:391) at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:347) at
>   android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:230) at
>   **android.widget.Toast.makeText**(Toast.java:253) at
>   com.anthonymandra.framework.ViewerActivity.**onActivityResult**(ViewerActivity.java:802)
>   at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:4581) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:2814) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:2861)
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:122) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1054)
>   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4123) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491) at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599) at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

This is the line of code called from within onActivityResult:

```
Toast.makeText(this, R.string.save_success, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Anyone know why a Toast might cause an ANR, or what might really be wrong if I'm misreading this?  Thanks!

Comment: Can you post some code from where you are calling Toast?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using direct call to `R.string`, you should use `getResources()` and then like below

```
String strSuccess = getString(R.string.save_success);
Toast.makeText(this, strSuccess, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

or

```
Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.save_success),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

[Read more](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getString%28int%29)

Comment: Why is it that you would suggest this?  The source for makeText is doing the same thing________________ return makeText(context, context.getResources().getText(resId), duration);

Comment: @Anthony, I edited my answer. Please clean your project and one more time try to run it.